# Memoization of slow URL get requests

Tags: python, async-await, redis

Purpose of this small module is to allow memoization of slow URL get requests. I intend to send many of these to download a bunch of files from internal (rather slow, old) website. Some requests may repeat many times - thus the memoization. Website is old so I'm limiting concurrent requests to 100.

I would love to hear code review remarks as I'm not a profession programmer but a user of python, so love to learn.

Thank you!

```
import os
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import functools
import aredis

proxy = os.environ.get("https_proxy")
redis = aredis.StrictRedis()
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)

async def cache_in(url, body):
    """Keep url-> body key value in redis"""
    return await redis.set(url, body)


async def cache_out(url):
    """Get url body out from redis"""
    return await redis.get(url)


def redismem(func):
    """Redis memoize decorator."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def inner(url):
        if body := await cache_out(url):
            return body
        body = await func(url)
        await cache_in(url, body)
        return body
    return inner


@redismem
async def get(url):
    """Get url"""
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with sem, session.get(url, proxy=proxy) as resp:
            body = await resp.read()
            return body
```

Comment: If you download files from a remote server, you have I/O bound processing. If your server is slow, you won’t speed up the overall processing with 100 concurrent requests. You may have good results with only one request at a time (w/o concurrency). However, using a cache is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you Laurent. The server is "modern" slow but can support up to ~100 concurrent requests. I have testested this, 100 concurrent requests is almost literally 100 times faster that 100 sequential.